# .htaccess not rewriting the URL correctly for .php files, but OK for .html files

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to accomplish 2 things in my `.htaccess`:

1. Redirect all requests for (in example) `www.blanklabs.com/boarddrive/faq`, `www.blanklabs.com/boarddrive/faq.htm`, `www.blanklabs.com/boarddrive/faq.html`, or `www.blanklabs.com/boarddrive/faq.php` to `www.blanklabs.com/boarddrive/faq.php`
2. The browser's address bar should show just `www.blanklabs.com/boarddrive/faq`, without the extension.

Here is my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# -- new
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

On the server I have `faq.html` (for now), but I also tried having both `faq.html` and `faq.php`. Eventually it'll just be `faq.php`.

The `.htaccess` is clearly incorrect, since if I go to `www.blanklabs.com/boarddrive/faq.html` I get the correct content (from `faq.html`), but if I go to `www.blanklabs.com/boarddrive/faq.php` I get a 500 error. This happens even if I have `faq.php` on the server.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? The no-extensions is secondary, the primary goal is to redirect all requests from `html` to `php` files.

Comment: Wait If you have faq.html and faq.php the rewrite condition you used wont match so there will be no rewrite. If you want faq.html to act like faq.php and url stays as /faq you should not have faq.html file at the first place and similarly no directory named /faq should be existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip POST requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.(php|html?)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(\.html?)?$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This correctly makes the address not have an extension, but I still get a 500 error when I go to either `faq.html` or `faq.php`. This happens if I have just `faq.html` in my server, just `faq.php`, or both.

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log to see why 500 is showing up?

Comment: It has this error: `File ".../blanklabs.com/boarddrive/faq.php" is writeable by group`. Is it some kind of a permission error? The permissions on the file are '666'

Comment: Right this is some permission related issue not rewrite related. Try making permission of that file as `644` using `chmod`.

Comment: Yes! Changing the permissions to 644 worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I realized that now with this setup I lose POST data after a redirect from "contact.php" to "contact". Is there something that can be changed to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect 
/faq.htm
/faq.php

[using redirect directive]

to /faq

now just applying rewrite rule to this later condition [/faq] to

/faq.php

It should work.